# Exclude a field during group stage of mongo aggregate pipeline but include it back at the end

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate

I have a mongo aggregate query like below:

```
db.someCollection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { taskId: "qy7u17-xunwqu" }
  },
  // Group by "tracklet_id" and calculate count for each group
  { 
    $group: {
      _id: '$tracklet_id',
      count: { $sum: 1 },
      representativeImage: { $first: '$img' }, // when I remove this, the query is done in a split second
      timestamp: { $max: '$timestamp' },
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      trackletId: '$_id',
      image: '$representativeImage', // but at the end, I want one representative image for a tracklet, doesn't matter which one.
      timestamp: 1,
      count: 1,
    },
  },
  { 
    $sort: {
      timestamp: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 20
  },
  
], {allowDiskUse: true})
```

the image field contains long b64 strings that take a lot of memory, causing the group and sort stage of the query to move to disk.
Is there a way that I can add a pipeline step before project to re-include an image field for each tracklet?

One alternative I can think of is to just do a separate query afterwards to get the images and combine the results, but I'm hoping there is a more elegant way to do it in the same aggregate query.

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/RSwHG-tVjZ3  not sure if a self lookup will slow even further tho

Comment: I thought about $lookup, but it fetches all documents matching the tracklet_id, while I only need one. I tried your suggestion on the db but it takes too long unfortunately.

Comment: can you try this too https://mongoplayground.net/p/ATBBoPX7DE-

Comment: Is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DCGXAVehXhS) what you are looking for? (Thanks @cmgchess for providing basis of playground)

Comment: @cmgchess, it worked amazingly well. Thanks man. Can you put it down as an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: @ray, it is an interesting approach, I'm not sure if it will return the same results as my intended query though. Let me give this a try and check

Comment: @ganjim they should be functionally the same, except the img being picked could be different. However, I don't see you imposed any sorting on the pick order, so I assumed picking any img inside the `tracklet_id` group will work

Comment: @ray Yes, picking any image is fine, the only sorting is on the latest timestamp for each tracklet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As verified by the OP.
Instead of having the image in the `$group` stage get the image from a self-lookup where you limit only to 1 doc (since we only need any single image and to save memory) that matches the same `trackletid`

```js
db.someCollection.aggregate([
  { $match: { taskId: "qy7u17-xunwqu" } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$tracklet_id",
      count: { $sum: 1 },
      timestamp: { $max: "$timestamp" }
    }
  },
  { $project: { _id: 0, trackletId: "$_id", timestamp: 1, count: 1 } },
  { $sort: { timestamp: -1 } },
  { $limit: 20 },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "someCollection",
      let: { trackletId: "$trackletId" },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $eq: [ "$tracklet_id", "$$trackletId" ] } } },
        { $limit: 1 },
        { $project: { _id: 0, img: 1 } }
      ],
      as: "image"
    }
  },
  { $addFields: { image: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$image.img", 0 ] } } }
])
```

[demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ATBBoPX7DE-)